# lagrangian minimisation problem and Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

A rectangular box without a lid is to be made from 50m² of cardboard. Find the maximum volume of such a box.( i know how to solve this in the conventional way, i am trying to figure out how to do it using this method, where the problem needs to be converted to a minimisation method then using the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions)

objective function and constraints will be:
$\max [f(x,y,z)]=xyz$
subject to $h(x,y,z)=xy+2yz+2zx-50=0$

Now to Convert to standard Lagrangian minimisation problem
I use the fact that $\min f(x)=\max -f(x)$
then the langrangian $$L(x,y,z)=f(x,y,z)-kc(x,y,z)=
-xyz-k(xy+2yz+2zx-50)$$
and this should now be a minimisation problem

The Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions state that for a minimisation problem:
$\nabla L(x^*,y^*,z^*,k^*)=0$ and $c(x^*,y^*,z^*)=0$ where the values of $x^*,y^* z^*$ are the solutions for the minimum.

then if i can show that the hessian matrix for the langrangian $L(x^*,y^*,z^*,k^*)$ is positive definite then this shows that the values i have found corespond to the global minimum.

I cant actually solve the equations $\nabla L(x*,y*,z*,k*)=0$ and $c(x*,y*,z*)=0$. When i put them in matrix form i get a mess, so this is what i am stuck on and i am starting to get a bit confused.

Comment: From $L_z = 0$ derive $k$ as a functions of $x,y$ and from $c = 0$ derive a constraint for $z$ as a function of $x,y$. Plug those into $L_x =0$ and $L_y = 0$ to get a nonlinear system with 2 equations and 2 unknowns. Both left-hand sides should be rational functions, so it should boil down to polynomial factoring.

Comment: As i said I'm stuck at this point. I have worked through deriving the expressions but have been unable to solve them, which is the point of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note first that since $L(x,y,z,k) = −xyz−k(xy+2z(x+y)−50) = L(y,x,z,k)$, the problem is symmetric in $x,y$.

Let's proceed with brutal arithmetic. We have 4 equations in 4 unknowns:

$$
\begin{split}
 0 &= -L_x = yz + k(y + 2z)\\
 0 &= -L_y = xz + k(x + 2z)\\
 0 &= -L_z = xy + 2k(x + y)\\
50 &= xy+2z(x+y) \quad (\text{from } c=0)
\end{split}
$$

**Claim 1.** $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$ and $x + y \neq 0$.

**Proof.**
Note first that if $x=0$, then the second constraint implies $k=0$ or $z=0$. If $x=k=0$, the first constraint implies $yz=0$ and the last constraint implies $2yz=50$, which is impossible.

Similarly, if $x=z=0$, the first constraint implies $ky = 0$. As we proved, $k=0$ is impossible, so must be $x=y=z=0$, which contradicts the last constraint.

To establish the last claim, note that if $x+y =0$, the third constraint yields $xy=0$ and the last one yields $xy=50$, which is a contradiction.
**QED**

Now, solving the last constraint for $z$ and the $L_z$ constraint for $k$, we get

$$k = \frac{-xy}{2(x+y)} \text{ and } z = \frac{50-xy}{2(x+y)}.$$

Both of these are well-defined since $x\neq0$ and $y \neq 0$. Plug both of these into the first constraint, getting

$$0 = \frac{y(50-xy)}{2(x+y)}
    - \frac{xy^2}{2(x+y)}
    - \frac{2xy(50-xy)}{2^2(x+y)^2}$$

and now multiply both sides by $2(x+y)^2 \neq 0$ to get

$$0 = y(50-xy)(x+y) - xy^2(x+y) - xy(50-xy).$$

Divide by $y \neq 0$ and bring the last term into the first term and divide by $y$ again:
$$
\begin{split}
 0 &= (50-xy)(x+y) - xy(x+y) - x(50-xy)\\
 0 &= y(50-xy) - xy(x+y) \\
 0 &= 50-xy - x(x+y) = 50 - 2xy - x^2\\
50 &= x^2 + 2xy
\end{split}
$$

and because the problem is symmetric, the symmetric constraint must hold (if you want, you can derive it the same way from the second constraint):

$$
\begin{split}
x^2 + 2xy &= 50 \\
y^2 + 2xy &= 50
\end{split}
$$

Hence subtracting them yields $x^2 = y^2$, so $x = \pm y$, but $x \neq -y$ by Claim 1, so $x = y$. Now $50 = x^2 + 2xy = 3x^2$ implies $x = \pm \sqrt{50/3} = y$, and there are two solutions: $(\sqrt{50},\sqrt{50})$ and $(-\sqrt{50},-\sqrt{50})$.

Since $x,y$ are lengths, we know only one will make sense: $x = y = \sqrt{50/3}$. Now plug this back in to find $z$ and $k$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks for that reply gt6989b, i ended up using maple to solve the equations.

Comment: Great answer. Question: can both equality constraint and its associated multiplier be zero, r does one zero exclude the other?

Comment: @Hass usually they are dual, so if one is non-zero the other is intended to be zero, but there is nothing forcing the other way, so if one is zero, not sure if it forces the other or not

Comment: @gt6989b Thanks. Can they be both zero, or that's not possible?

Comment: @Hass I think they can...